# Syntax Error on Formula

Tags: formula

```
IF(LastActivityDate <= 90 Day, checked = true, checked = false)
```

Can someone please help me with this formula?  I am getting a syntax error and I think it might have to do with the `Day`, but not 100% sure.

Comment: What does`checked = true` mean? Are you trying to set a field? Or do a Validation Rule? Or something else?

Answer (score 2):

A Boolean operator is already a Boolean. Therefore, all you need to do is compare to if it's less than 90 days. Subtracting two dates results in a number in terms of number of days. So, your formula should be either:

```
// Displays checked if it has been more than 90 days
TODAY() - DATEVALUE(LastActivityDate) > 90

--- or ---

// Displays checked if it has not yet been 90 days
TODAY() - DATEVALUE(LastActivityDate) <= 90
```

Comment: Ha. Good catch on wrong operator.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 (Now() - LastActivityDate) <= 90
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `TODAY()`?

Comment: I am not sure whether its Date or DateTime. Because I tried this in my DE org and it worked fine `IF((Now()- CreatedDate) <= 90,true,false)`.

Comment: Fair enough. Just fyi `IF(condition, true, false)` is identical to (and more verbose than) just `condition`.

Comment: Yeah I observed the edit, it is short and sweet now :)

Comment: I went with this: TODAY() - LastActivityDate) <= 90